# Fixing the following error message for the simple substitution $ j[bb, a1, a2] //. {j[bb, ll__] -> List[ll].List[b1, b2]} $

Tags: warning-messages, error-tracking

For a given Mathematica code

```
 j[bb, a1, a2] //. {j[bb, ll__] -> List[ll].List[b1, b2]}
```

I obtain the desired answer which is

```
 a1 b1 + a2 b2
```

But having a problem with the error

[image]

How one can avoid this error message? For this simple case it work perfectly, but I am worried about for some complicated cases that I am going to deal with.

Comment: You should use `RuleDelayed`. ``j[bb, a1, a2] //. {j[bb, ll__] :> List[ll] . List[b1, b2]} ``

Comment: The problem is that in "->" the RHS is evaluated before it is used.  In this case, evaluation has no effect, but triggers a warning, because the RHS looks like a mistake.  If you replace "->" with ":>" the RHS is not evaluated before substitution, so the problem does not arise.